# Filtering a pandas column which contains a list in other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe pd like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7K2i.jpg

I want to filter the df_participants column which contains `pd['df_pair'][0]`, and the expected result should be a new pd1 containing only rows that `pd['df_pair'][0]` is a subset of df_paticipants like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWK69.jpg

I have no idea how to do that. I have tried with `.isin()` or `pd1 = pd[pd['df_participants'].str.contains(pd['df_pair'][0])]` but it does not work. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `pd` variable is not good idea for `DataFrame`, better is use `df`:

```
#remove nans rows
df = df.dropna(subset=['df_participants'])

#get rows if subset
df = df[df.df_participants.map(set(df['df_pair'][0]).issubset)]
```

Comment: what pandas version are you using? I got this error

 File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2859, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @MarkNguyen - Answer was edited.

Comment: thank you. After removing nan it works now, but the result is not correct. It accepts either '27' or '30'.  The pair '27' and '30' should be subset. ???@jezrael

Comment: @MarkNguyen - exactly, subset is `27` and `30`

Comment: For example, ['18', '27', '112'] or ['30', '39', '62', '16'] is not correct. I want ['27', '30', '39', '62', '17']. That's what I got.

Comment: @MarkNguyen - You are right, need `isisubset`, answer was edited.